Existing Cognito resources with Microsoft Entra using SAML
The Cognito resources have been built using terraform
I am building a simple one-page web app and do not want to use the AWS Hosted UI. I have the following JS config with amplify
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      region: eu-west-2
      userPoolId: eu-west-2_abcd1234
      userPoolClientId: 'abcd',
      authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH',

      // Add OAuth/Federation configuration
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          domain: 'https://auth.abcd.io',
          scopes: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
          redirectSignIn: [
            'https://web.abcd.io'
          ],
          redirectSignOut: [
            'https://web.abcd.io'
          ],
          responseType: 'code',
          providers: ['SAML']
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

and the SSO button calls the following function
export const signInWithMicrosoft = async () => {
  try {
    await signInWithRedirect({
      provider: {
        custom: 'ms-entra-saml'
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error signing in with Microsoft:', error)
    throw error
  }
}

When clicking the SSO button it takes me to the Microsoft website and I enter the login details.  This part seems to work fine. I then get redirected back to https://auth.abcd.io/error?null and it displays

Login option is not available. Please try another one

Any help would be great .. I don't have much experience with JS/Frontend so maybe i am missing something very simple ..
